# Match words that starts with TE and have exactly 11 characters

Tags: regex

As the title says, I'm trying to match words that start with TE and have exactly 11 characters from a string.

What I've done is `/TE\w+/g` which match all words that starts with TE in a string. Then I tried to match the words with 11 characters: `/TE{11}\w+/g`, but it's not working.

So, in this example `blablabla TE123 blablabla TE123456789 blabla` I want to match only `TE123456789`.

What is the `regex` for it?

Comment: Use `/\bTE\w{9}\b/g` - `TE` = 2 chars, `\w{9}` = 9 chars > 11 chars all in all

Comment: Hey @WiktorStribiżew your answer is almost right. It's 9 instead of 8. Please post the answer and I'll mark it as the correct answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
/\bTE\w{9}\b/g
```

`TE` is 2 chars, and `\w{9}` matches 9 chars, the `\b` word boundary tells to fail the match if there are more chars on the right, making it 11 chars all in all.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AbtZKP/1) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5CbTE%5Cw%7B9%7D%5Cb):

[image]

To only match letter words, replace `\w` with `[a-zA-Z]` or `\p{L}` (that matches any Unicode letter). Something like

```
/\bTE[a-zA-Z]{9}\b/g
/\bTE\p{L}{9}\b/gu
```

These are modern JavaScript engine compliant patterns.